# Error code "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when using json_encode (oop, php)

Tags: php, json, class, decode, encode

I'm trying to create a to do list. When creating new posts it should encode the information to json and put the information in a json array. But somehow it seems the information isn't encoded correctly and when trying to print the posts I get the error message "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I just can't find where the mistake is.

I'm fairly new at this so to complex answers might be to hard for me to understand.

Edit:
Adding the whole freaking code. Something is seriously wrong. ‍♀️

index:

```
    <?php 

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include $class . '.class.php';
});

$allPosts = new Lista;

if(isset($_REQUEST['addNewPost'])){
    $allPosts->addNewPost($_REQUEST['ett'], $_REQUEST['tva'], $_REQUEST['tre']);
}
?>

<?php $page_title = "Att göra lista";
include("includes/header.php");
?>
<?php
include("includes/sidebar.php");
?>
<h2>Min att göra lista</h2>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
Uppgift: <input type="text" name="ett"/><br/>
Utfarare: <input type="text" name="tva"/><br/>
Senast: <input type="text" name="tre"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="addNewPost" value="Lägg till post"/>
</form>


<?php
  //Loopa igenom array
  foreach ($allPosts->getTheList() as $key=>$val) {
   echo "<section id='postPart'>" . $val->getEtt() . "<br/>" . $val->getTva(). " " . $val->getTre(). "</section><section id='buttonPart'><button type='button' name='klar'>Avklarad!</button> <button type='button' name='deletePost'>Ta bort</button>\n";
}

//echo "<section id='postPart'>" . $_REQUEST['one'] . "<br/>" . $_REQUEST['two'] . " " . $_REQUEST['three'] . "</section><section id='buttonPart'><button type='button' name='klar'>Avklarad!</button> <button type='button' name='deletePost'>Ta bort</button>\n";


var_dump($allPosts);
 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Class: Lista:

```
 <?php
class Lista{
    public $theList=[];

        function __construct(){
            if(file_exists("text.json")>0)
                $this->theList = json_decode(file_get_contents('text.json'), true);
        }

        function addNewPost($ett, $tva, $tre){
            $posten = new Post ($ett, $tva, $tre);
            array_push ($this->theList, $posten);
            $jsonStr = json_encode($this->theList);
            file_put_contents("text.json", $jsonStr);
        }

        function getTheList( ){
            return $this->theList;
        }

}
```

Class Post:

```
<?php
class Post{
    public $ett;
    public $tva;
    public $tre;

    function __construct ($ett, $tva, $tre){
        $this->ett = $ett;
        $this->tva = $tva;
        $this->tre = $tre;
    }

    function getEtt():string{
        return $this->ett;
    }

    function getTva(){
        return $this->tva;
    }

    function getTre(){
        return $this->tre;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the foreach, enable error reporting, `$this->$thePost` is wrong

Comment: `$thePost` is an object, and then you are using as an attribute in `$this->$thePost`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the foreach is there now to.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I've tried to remove the "this->" part but that did nothing. I've never used php classes so I get confused with what is what right now. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the typo, to json_encode an array of objects your need to make an exporter method which returns an array of each property or implement [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php)

```
<?php
class Post implements JsonSerializable {
    protected $whatIs = ' ';
    protected $whoIs = ' ';
    protected $whenIs = ' ';
    
    function __construct($what,$who,$when){
        $this->whatIs=$what;
        $this->whoIs=$who;
        $this->whenIs=$when;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}

$arr = [];

$arr[] = new Post(1,2,3);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Result:

```
[{"whatIs":1,"whoIs":2,"whenIs":3}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I've implemented this right (should all the code be in the "Post" class page?) but I have been able to remove the error code, but still nothing is written in my .json file. I get no error codes at all, but nothing is echoed and nothing in my .json file. I have started over three times but still can't get it to work. Btw, where is there a typo?

Comment: typo was @spzout's answer. if nothing is being written to the file then you might have a permissions issue, that would show in the error log, always enable error reporting when developing. If it is writing to it but your getting `[{},{},{}]` then its related to my answer. Add all your code or share a git repo, cant really tell what the issue is with a few snippets, like have you checked the form is sending up the values?

Comment: also note once you encoded the class to json and saved to file, it wont maintain the methods/getters for the class, on read-back it will simply be an array, if you want all that you should use [serialise](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) instead of json_encode

Comment: The code is sending values and has now started (finally!) to write in my .json file. There is still the problem with the foreach loop though, but now it says there is a stack trace #0 issue instead. I have to use json since the assignment is to get the to do posts from the .json file. That's why I try with the not working foreach loop.

Comment: as said the getters wont exist, do a `print_r($allPosts->getTheList());` where that foreach is and your see its an a normal array, so you cant be doing `$val->getEtt()`, whilst `$val['ett']` should work

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is on this line:

```
$jsonStr = json_encode($this->$thePost, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

You might be trying to do this :

```
$jsonStr = json_encode($thePost, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Since $thePost is an object, and not a property of your class. It could work if $thePost is a string that match a property name.

Comment: what about the objects in the array?

Comment: This didn't do any difference, I have been able to remove the error code, but still nothing is written in my .json or echoed out to screen. It's like it's stopped somewhere on the way.